# ethers.BigNumber.toNumber is not a function

Tags: ethers.js, bignumber

```
const { ethers } = require('ethers');
console.log(ethers.BigNumber.isBigNumber(totalBalance));
```

**Returns true**

```
const { ethers } = require('ethers');
console.log(ethers.BigNumber.toNumber(totalBalance));
```

**ethers.BigNumber.toNumber is not a function**

According to the docs

https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/#BigNumber

`toNumber()` is a function on `BigNumber`.

Are the docs wrong or is maybe `toNumber` called wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `isBigNumber` is a static method of class `ethers.BigNumber`.

As you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static):

> The **static** keyword defines a static method or property for a class. Neither static methods nor static properties can be called on instances of the class. Instead, they're called on the class itself.

---

The method `toNumber`, on the other hand, is not a static method of class `ethers.BigNumber`.

Therefore, it should be called on instances of the class rather than on the class itself.

So in short, you need to change this:

```
ethers.BigNumber.toNumber(totalBalance)
```

To this:

```
ethers.BigNumber(totalBalance).toNumber()
```

Answer (score 0):

if the `totalBalance` is the bignumber or the value format seem like this..

```
BigNumber {_hex: '0x02', _isBigNumber: true}
```

you just add toNumber after `totalBalance`

`totalBalance.toNumber()`  // result = 2